# Recreate fipy Grid2D with Mesh2D constructor

Tags: fipy

If I create a fipy 2D grid using:

```
mesh = Grid2D(nx=3, ny=3, dx=1., dy=1.)
```

I get a reasonable grid of rectangular elements. However, if I take the values of this mesh and use them to construct a vanilla `Mesh2D`:

```
mesh2d = Mesh2D(mesh.vertexCoords, mesh.faceVertexIDs, mesh.cellFaceIDs)
```

I get a mesh that is triangular, and some of the triangles seem to be invalid. If I do this:

```
model = CellVariable(mesh=mesh2d, value=1.)
```

and view it with the matplotlib viewer, some of the triangles are unfilled, which I assume means they are not valid.

Can I recreate the original rectangular grid using `Mesh2D`? I would like to do this because I have distorted rectangular grid coordinates from another source that I'd like substitute for `mesh.vectorCoords` in the call to `Mesh2D`. The face vertices and the cell faces are the same, it's just the mesh fabric that has been distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid2D` has a number of optimizations that are self-consistent, both with solving and viewing, but that don't translate to the general meshes. You can achieve what you want by instead doing

```
mesh = fipy.meshes.nonUniformGrid2D.NonUniformGrid2D(nx=3, ny=3, dx=1., dy=1.)
mesh2d = Mesh2D(mesh.vertexCoords, mesh.faceVertexIDs, mesh.cellFaceIDs)
model = CellVariable(mesh=mesh2d, value=1.)
```

Comment: I don't follow. I'm not solving or viewing with Grid2D, but on Mesh2D. How can I use NonUniformGrid2D to set up a distorted mesh? The manual unfortunately says very little about this class. Right now, I only use Grid2D as a source of mesh connections required by the Mesh2D constructor, replacing the vertex coordinates with my own.

Comment: Replace line 1 of your your code with the line I gave, then define `mesh2d` as you already do. `NonUniformGrid2D` has the topology you want, `Grid2D` does not.

Comment: Edited to clarify

Comment: This seems to work, but my boundary conditions seem to be enforced only at the most extreme points on the mesh rather than the entire boundary. E.g. `myVar.constrain(1.0, mesh2d.facesBottom)` doesn't constrain the bottom faces. It just constrains the bottommost point, giving the solution a bright spot there. Is there something special I have to do to enforce the BC properly?

Comment: You would need to define a mask that captures the faces you want. `facesBottom` et al. are just extrema tests. If I wanted to distort a grid, I would use Gmsh, which enables identifying physical boundaries as part of the definition.

Comment: Actually, just using `mesh.facesBottom` in the constraint worked, since it's just a mask.

Comment: ??? What does "E.g. `myVar.constrain(1.0, mesh2d.facesBottom)` doesn't constrain the bottom faces" mean, then?

Comment: You have `mesh2d`. I used `mesh.facesBottom`, not `mesh2d.facesBottom`, and that worked. I used the mask from the rectangular mesh.

Comment: Ah, I see. Rather clever.

Answer (score 1):

I think the viewer is unable to display the Mesh2D mesh class rather than anything that is fundamentally wrong with using a Mesh2D object to solve equations. To demonstrate this, you can solve a simple equation using a Mesh2D and then map back to a Grid2D to display your data. For example,

```
import fipy

mesh = fipy.Grid2D(nx=3, ny=3, dx=1., dy=1.)
mesh2d = fipy.meshes.mesh2D.Mesh2D(mesh.vertexCoords, mesh.faceVertexIDs, mesh.cellFaceIDs)

var = fipy.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=1.)
var2D = fipy.CellVariable(mesh=mesh2d, value=1.)

var2D.constrain(2, where=mesh.facesRight)
var2D.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)

fipy.DiffusionTerm().solve(var2D)


var[:] = var2D(mesh.cellCenters, order=1)

fipy.Viewer(var).plot()
raw_input('stop')
```

and the result looks correct. We've solved an equation using a variable on the `Mesh2D` and it seems to work just fine.

The above is using the `__call__` method of `CellVariable` to interpolate back to the variable on the `Grid2D`. This approach will work for your distorted grid as well. The interpolation is first order only.